# How to get the full url for an asset in Controller?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I need to generate some JSON content in controller and I need to get the full URL to an uploaded image situated here : `/web/uploads/myimage.jpg`.

How can I get the full url of it?

`http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/myimage.jpg`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can generate the url from the request object:

```
$baseurl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath();
```

You could make a twig extension that cuts the `/web` part of your path and uses the request to generate the base url.

see `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator::doGenerate` for a more solid implementation.

Also, Twig has access to the request from `app.request`.

Comment: `$request = $this->getRequest();`

Comment: `getRequest()` is deprecated in favor of the injection of the `Request`object

Comment: `$request = $this->container->get('request');` when you can't inject the Request object (e.g. overwriting setContainer() that has a predefined signature)

Answer (score 48):

You can use this in Controller:

```
$this->getRequest()->getUriForPath('/uploads/myimage.jpg');
```

**EDIT :** This method also includes the `app.php` and `app_dev.php` to the url. Meaning **this will only work in production when url-rewriting is enabled**!

Comment: To me, this solution worked in the development environment as well.

Comment: @RayOnAir, the problem is that if you're using the `app_dev.php` url, an asset will be appended to this url, e.g. `http://bla.com/app_dev.php/uploads/test.png` - which doesn't exist.

Comment: Not working in Symfony 2.5. This code returns URL with the app.php or app_dev.php included in the path. By the way it can be used, but you got to use str_replace() to produce legal URL.

Comment: THX. Working fine in Symfony 3.4.13 . $request->getUriForPath('/uploads/myimage.jpg');

Comment: Works in Symfony 5.2 as well.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the `templating.helper.assets` service.

First define your [assets base URL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls) :

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/"
```

Then just call the service from within your controller, command or wherever you are :

```
<?php

// src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php

namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $myAssetUrl = $this
            ->get('templating.helper.assets')
            ->getUrl('bundles/acmedemo/js/main.js', $packageName = null)
        ;

        // $myAssetUrl is "http://www.mywebsite.com/bundles/acmedemo/js/main.js"

        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, as it is the most flexible one! You can put your assets anywhere you want (i.e. a CDN) in the future and only change the assets_base_url value in your config file.

Comment: Keep in mind that `templating.helper.assets` is only available when `php` templating engine is enabled.

Comment: with Symfony 3.0+, the equivalent service to fetch asset information within PHP is `assets.packages`.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get this url from within a twig template use:

```
{{ app.request.uriForPath('/uploads/myimage.jpg') }}
```

Comment: or {{ asset('/uploads/myimage.jpg') }}. Not that the question relates to a view, just saying there is an easier way in twig =)

Comment: @MattiasSvensson `asset` gives me full path, but not uri (not absolute)

Comment: The question was 'in Controller' not in twig

Comment: @barius asset has an absolute option

Comment: works fine with assetic :

{% image '@AcmeBundle/Resources/public/images/myimage.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ app.request.uriForPath(asset_url) }}">
{% endimage %}

Answer (score 12):

As of Symfony **2.1** you can use:

```
$request->getSchemeAndHttpHost().'/uploads/myimage.jpg';
```

**Note**: This solution has the advantage to work in **both** DEV and PROD environments.

Answer (score 10):

The best solution would be IMHO to look at `Twig`'s implementation of `asset`, which you can find in:

```
\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Extension\AssetsExtension
```

in the method:

```
public function getAssetUrl($path, $packageName = null, $absolute = false, $version = null)
```

which basically uses the `templating.helper.assets` service similar to @iamdto's answer:

```
$url = $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($path, $packageName, $version);
```

Or directly use the `AssetsExtension` service or class respectively.

Comment: Yep, using the extension helper of the "asset" twig function is the most secure way. Thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

```
app.request.uriForPath('/uploads/myimage.jpg') | replace({'/app_dev.php': ''})
```

this avoid the problem of app_dev.php

Comment: The questioner asked for controller code, this is twig. If you don't want app_dev.php added to your URLs you should simply use the prod controller (app.php or simply "/" if it's configured right).

Comment: thanks Nacho, very useful as quick and dirty test ;)

Answer (score 3):

This solution doesn't require adding any variable or parameter on config and is the same function that is used by Twig for `{{ absolute_url() }}`

```
public function yourAction(AssetsHelper $assetsHelper, HttpFoundationExtension $httpExtension)
{
    $assetsPath = $assetsHelper->getUrl('/img/test.jpg');
    $assetFullUrl = $httpExtension->generateAbsoluteUrl($assetPath);
}
```

The complete url of your asset will be on `$assetFullUrl`

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me

```
$baseurl = $this->getRequest()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost() . $this->getRequest()->getBasePath();
```

Comment: This will do the trick. After this code concate your folder and the image filename.

Comment: But there is a shortcut as of Symfony 2.1, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Method `app.request.uriForPath()` gives an absolute URL from a path. Helper `asset()` gives the path of an asset.

```
{{ app.request.uriForPath(asset('bundles/mybundle/images/name.png')) }}
```

It's important to have both for the case where the application is not at the root of the domain, for eg:

```
http://mydomain.com/myapp/app.php
```

Answer (score 2):

For CDNs, you can also inject the `Packages` directly into your service.

First the asset base url in config.yml:

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_url:
            - 'http://cdn.mysite.com'
```

Then the fun part:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;

class SomeClass
{
    private $packages;

    public function __construct(Packages $packages)
    {
        $this->packages = $packages;
    }

    public function proxyToAssetUrl(string $path): string
    {
        return $this->packages->getUrl($path);
    }
}
```

If you have autowiring enabled then you won't need to configure anything in your `services.yml`, otherwise something like:

```
services:
    App\Service\SomeClass:
        class: App\Service\SomeClass
        arguments: ['@assets.packages']
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Al Jey solution works fine with Assetic (tested on Symfony 2.6)

```
{% image '@AcmeBundle/Resources/public/images/myimage.jpg' %} 
    <img src="{{ app.request.uriForPath(asset_url) }}"> 
{% endimage %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution in Symfony 3.3+

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    ...
    base_url: 'http://mywebsite.com'
```

To get it in your controller action:

```
$baseUrl = $this->getParameter('base_url');
```

You can now append your image to it e-g: `$baseUrl . '/uploads/' . $image` or if you like you can define uploaded assets base url in config.yml and access it in controller action.

Best thing about this solution would be the ability to pre-define it for different environments e-g: in `config.yml`,  `config_dev.yml` and `config_test.yml` so when you move your project between different environments, you don't have to change it as it's already there..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **getSchemeAndHttpHost()** for Gets the scheme and HTTP host and  use the function **getBasePath()** to get the root path from which this request is executed

```
$request->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$request->getBasePath()."/uploads/myimage.jpg"
```

This method works fine for the app.php and app_dev.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\HttpFoundationExtension $httpFoundationExtension->generateAbsoluteUrl('url');`

Service ID is `twig.extension.httpfoundation` if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found (at least with version 6) is to use UrlHelper to convert a relative URL into an absolute URL.

For example for an asset managed with Packages you can use something like:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UrlHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;

//...

function __construct(private UrlHelper $urlHelper, private Packages $packages) { }

//...

$absoluteURL = $this->urlHelper->getAbsoluteUrl($this->packages->getUrl('build/images/logo.png'))
```

Note that to use UrlHelper there should be a Request (you don't need to pass it but it should exist).

Answer (score -1):

You can get site url i.e point to web folder by using the following code

$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';

```
    $hostName = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');

    $baseDirectory = "";

    if(!empty($this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getBaseUrl())){

        $baseDirectory = str_replace('app_dev.php', '', $this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getBaseUrl());
    }

    $rootUrl = $protocol.$hostName.$baseDirectory;
```