# access static file within bundle controller/service etc

Tags: symfony

I am new in symfony2. i am stuck at small problem.
my directory path is like this

project

```
/app
/bin
/src
  /neil
    /mybundle
       /Controller  
       /DependencyInjection
       /EventListner
       /Helper
       /Resources
         /public
           /js
            /script.js
       /Services
       /Test
/vendor
/web
```

I want to access the url of script.js in my controller/services(not in template). How would i do it.

edit: I have tried

```
$fileLocator = $this->container->get('file_locator');
        $path = $fileLocator->locate('@neilmybundle/Resources/public/js/script.js');
```

It returns directory path.
If i use this directory path  like

```
$r = '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$path.'"></script>';

        return new Response($r);
```

It does not source the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585474/accessing-files-relative-to-bundle-in-symfony2

Comment: @Neil you can try the [Finder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) component

Comment: Why do you need to do this? FYI, resources/public get installed to the web directory for web use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16498845/1353837

I think you should execute `app/console assets:install` before

Answer (score 1):

In your controller/service, you can inject the kernel (or grab it from the container) and use locateResource(). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7587106/4000591