# How do I get the absolute path of the assets folder from the Asset component in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm uploading and saving images to the assets folder and I need to get the absolute path. I could have hard coded it but it would be all wrong if I was to deploy the app to a server with different folder structure. So I need the Asset component.

In the twig template, I can call

```
<img src="{{ asset("assets/img/" ~ image) }}">
```

and it will all work. But how do I use it in the controller and return only the path?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16498845/3693616

Comment: You could find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163803/how-to-get-assets-img-url-in-symfony-controller

Comment: I don't want to return the path for the file, I want to get path of the assets folder, something like http://example.com/assets/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Package;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\EmptyVersionStrategy;

$package = new Package(new EmptyVersionStrategy());

$imageUrl = $package->getUrl('/');
```