# Get base url on symfony 3.4 command

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-4.4

I'm trying to get the base url on a command to get localhost on local and the production url on producction but all the exmaples I found are using the reuqest object but I
don't have it on a command:

```
class PasswordExpirationCommand extends Command
{
    private $ms;
    private $translator;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(MailService $ms, TranslatorInterface $translator, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->ms = $ms;
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:password:expiration')
            ->setDescription('Expire 3 months old password');
    }

    /**
     *
     *  
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int|void|null
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $base_url =....//need http://localhost/ or https://production_url 
        //reminders
        $this->passwordExpirationReminder();
    }
```

Comment: I think you can't do that, you should inject a parameter into the command

Comment: And it's described [in the manual](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/request_context.html).

Comment: You can check the link below. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811251/how-to-get-the-full-url-for-an-asset-in-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811251/how-to-get-the-full-url-for-an-asset-in-controller)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed [dotenv](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html) component so you can set a new variable in your .env file

```
BASE_URL = 'your_url' //need http://localhost/ or https://production_url
```

If not you can put it in *parameters.yml* it's a good practice also.

Then get it by (it depends in witch version of sf you have)

```
 $base_url = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('translator')
```

**Don't forget to extends your command from *ContainerAwareCommand* instead of *Command* to have access to the container**